# spacemacs vi bindings not working

Tags: vim, emacs, evil-mode, spacemacs

I am using spacemacs in GUI mode.

I was going through evil-tutor inside spacemacs. It told me to hit "j" to jump to next section. I was unable to do so since it was typing the letter "j" instead inside the buffer.

Similarly, I was unable to give commands such as ":qa! < ENTER >" and "x" to delete the character below the cursor. It just inserts the text.

help!

Comment: If you look in your .spacemacs file, what value is dotspacemacs-editing-style set to? If it's set to 'emacs or 'hybrid, you won't be getting the vim key-bindings. Disclaimer, I've never tried using spacemacs with anything but straight emacs key-bindings.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks!